# How we take just two numbers in Perl using rand?

Tags: perl, random

In Perl using rand can we exclude number between max and min except some number.

Max 3 Min 1

X = Int (rand(max - min + 1) + min )

Result will be 1 and 2 and 3

I want to except 2 how did it in Perl?

Comment: Just do a rand from min to max-1 and then say your exclusion is the number $x you do for your rand result $r: `$r++ if $r >= $x;` - you'd do the same for any language, just add 1 if you hit >= of your excluded number.

Comment: This not work because if i did r++ i get always same resualt. $r= 2 $r++ will be 3 .but i want next time to be 1 not 3 .i mean i need just rand for those two value (1.3)

Comment: integer or float numbers in that interval?

Comment: ` perl -E '@vals = (1,3);for(0..10){say $vals[int rand(2)]}'`

Comment: Interger Miguel prz

Comment: @jaafarfawzi You first do `$r = rand(int($max-$min))+$min` THEN on the result you do `$r++ if $r >= $x;` If the random result was 1, it stays 1, if the random result was 2 it becomes 3 etc. For large numbers this is quite a bit faster than the solutions where you generate an array with exclusions.

Comment: Dear ecuador as i said above if resault is 2 i want it to be 1 or 3 not only 3 .so r++ it only r will be 3 .but i want next time to be 1

Answer (score 1):

Simple, extensible approach:

```perl
my @nums = grep { $_ != $exclude } $min..$max;
my $n = int( rand( @nums ) );
```

Avoids building an array:

```perl
my $n = int( rand( $max - $min ) );
$n += $min;
++$n if $n >= $exclude;
```

For picking between two values:

```perl
my $n = rand() >= 0.5 ? $min : $max;
```

Comment: In the 1st approach, did you mean `$n = $nums[int(rand(@nums))]`? ;-)

Comment: @Dada, Indeed, replaced.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly from comments, you want to select randomly from two possible values, right?

You can do it using a *ternary operator* like this:

```perl
$x = rand > 0.5 ? $min : $max;
```

In your particular example it can be:

```perl
$x = rand > 0.5 ? 1 : 3;
```